# Kotlin delegated property setValue cannot be kept

Tags: kotlin, delegates

I am reading this [page](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/07_Delegation/02_DelegatedProperties) about `Delegated properties` in Kotlin doc site.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class Example {
    var p: String by Delegate()                                               // 1

    override fun toString() = "Example Class"
}

class Delegate() {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): String {        // 2     
        return "$thisRef, thank you for delegating '${prop.name}' to me!"
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: String) { // 2
        println("$value has been assigned to ${prop.name} in $thisRef")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val e = Example()
    println(e.p)
    e.p = "NEW"
}
```

The output is:

```
Example Class, thank you for delegating 'p' to me!
NEW has been assigned to p in Example Class
```

And I can understand the result.

But my question is, what if I print the `e.p` again after setting its value as `NEW`:

```
fun main() {
    val e = Example()
    println(e.p)
    e.p = "NEW"
    println(e.p) // print it again after setting new value on it
}
```

I expect it to print `NEW`. But the actual result is, it kept the same as the 1st println: `Example Class, thank you for delegating 'p' to me!`.

Kotlin playground at [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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).

Seems like the `e.p = "NEW"` cannot change the value correctly. What causes that? What do I do if I want to set the value as `NEW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate class instance completely takes over what the getter and setter of the property do. Since your delegate’s `setValue` function doesn’t actually store the passed-in value in any internal property, it’s `getValue` function has no way to retrieve and return it. And indeed, the implementation of `getValue()` in your code is only generating a String and returning that.

When you get the value of the delegated property, it returns whatever your delegate returns in `getValue()`, so the behavior is determined by how you program your delegate class.

Comment: Thanks! Got it, it turns out it's no mystery in the setValue / getValue themselves, it is the Delegate class implementation to return and update the value of the delegated property. Clear! Thank you!